# I have a list built on external content using bdc with a custom filter, I get the data but not the filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, external-content-type, sql, bdc

SPD 2013, SP Enterprise 2013, SQL 2008

So I have a BDC connector setup with a SQL backend, I then built a Exernal Content List off that.  I then inserted a content control webpart and inserted some html/js to build a set of search boxes that build control searches and url queries.  I then added parameters for the url query and used the finder to tied the url queries back to the filters I used with the ECT.

Now.. I had all of this working but the Sharepoint designed corupted the file and would not allow me to do anything, so I had saved my script and I just rebuilt it, it was working before the coruption.  Now its not working and I have been back through all my steps about 10 times and just can not figure out why I can not get the query string parameters to apply to the ECT.  I think this is something querky with SPD and not the actual setup but not even sure where to look.

Help please.

[image: External Content Type Read List]

[image: FilterLocation]

```
        <ParameterBinding Name="FltLocation" Location="QueryString(FltLocation)" DefaultValue="**"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="FltAssetNumber" Location="QueryString(FltAssetNumber)" DefaultValue="**"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="FltAudit" Location="QueryString(FltAudit)" DefaultValue="**"/>
```

and

```
<Method Name="Read List">
                <Filter Name="FilterLocation" Value="*[FltLocation]*"/>
                <Filter Name="FilterAssetNo" Value="*[FltAssetNumber]*"/>
                <Filter Name="FilterAudit" Value="*[FltAudit]*"/>
            </Method>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get solution to this? I am facing same issue